# Hibernate seems to see private fields of entity

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

We all know that, `private` members are not inherited in JAVA, or more specifically, private member variables are not visible in the child class.
So, if I have a super class A as follows :

```
 public class A {

      private int a;
      public int b;

 }
```

and there is other class B, which extends A as follows:

```
 public class B extends A{}
```

now I have a following code snippet:

```
 class b = new B();
 System.out.println(b.a);    //  Not possible since 'a' is declared privtate
 System.out.println(b.a);    // this is possible
```

Now, I have a following code that I am using in a hibernate tutorial.
(Example involves Table_PER_CLASS strategy.)
Here is the code,

```
  public class Vehicle {
  @Id
  private int vehicleId;
  private String vehicleName;

  public String getVehicleName() {
    return vehicleName;
  }

  public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
    this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
  }

  public Vehicle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public int getVehicleId() {
    return vehicleId;
  }

  public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
    this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
  }

}
```

And I have a TwoWheeler class as follows:

```
 @Entity
 public class TwoWheeler extends Vehicle {

 private String SteeringHandle;

  public String getSteeringHandle() {
    return SteeringHandle;
   }

   public void setSteeringHandle(String steeringHandle) {
    SteeringHandle = steeringHandle;
   }
 }
```

When I run this code, a TwoWheeler table is created with following columns:

```
 +-----------+-------------+----------------------+
 | vehicleId | vehicleName | SteeringHandle       |
 +-----------+-------------+----------------------+
 |         2 | Bike        | Bike Steering Handle |
 +-----------+-------------+----------------------+
```

But `vehicleId` and `vehicleName` are private members of Vehicle class.
Then How are they inherited in the hibernate when the tables are created in the database?

Comment: Try writing something like `(new TwoWheeler()).setVehicleName("Test");` and you see that it is indeed possible.

Comment: In regards to the example, you should put the `@Id` annotation on field if you plan to access the field, but because it is private you plan to access it via getter, so the getter should be annotated instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate accesses the fields using the getters and setters methods... Which are public

Comment: No, your answer doesn't help me at all. I edited the Vehicle class to have private int val = 10 and re-run the code without any getter-setter methods. val column was added in the TwoWheeler.

Comment: @NeerajDorle do u mean, have you removed getter setter method?

Comment: I did not add any for the val field

Comment: @NeerajDorle Hibernate uses reflection to access the fields, because Hibernate has to instantiate arbitrary classes basing on the table name and can't rely on "normal" methods.

Comment: This would be true if the entity used property based access, but it is using field access as the id field is annotated with `@Id` and not the getter or setter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question -  How are they inherited in the hibernate when the tables are created in the database?
Hibernate is an orm framework which internally uses reflection.
The inheritance or binding is done at run-time.Since your TwoWheeler class has parent class with no explicit inheritance strategy, default strategy -SINGLE_TABLE is used. Based on inheritance strategy query is generated which gets executed to map relation in database.

Answer (score 0):

Because you annotated the field `vehicalId` with `@Id` annotation, hibernate inferred that you are using [AccessType.FIELD](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AccessType.html#FIELD) and used Java reflection to read all fields from the class to determine list of the entity's properties (this includes private fields aswell).

If you would annotate the id getter `getVehicalId()` with `@Id` you would be using [AccessType.PROPERTY](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AccessType.html#PROPERTY) and hibernate would infer list of properties from the getters/setters pretty much the same way.

So while private fields of super class are invisible to you by conventional ways, they are accessible to you and hibernate via reflection.